# MongoDB C# driver: transaction fails in Mongo Atlas

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to implement transaction on my free tier Mongo Atlas cluster using C# driver.

This is what I have so far:

Unit Of Work part:

```
public class MongoContext : IMongoContext
{
    //...
    public IClientSessionHandle Session { get; private set; }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var opt = new ClientSessionOptions();
        using (Session = await _mongoClient.StartSessionAsync(opt, cancellationToken))
        {
            Session.StartTransaction();

            var commandTasks = _commands.Select(c => c()).ToList();

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(commandTasks);
                // foreach (var commandTask in commandTasks)
                // {
                //     await commandTask;
                // }
                await Session.CommitTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                _logger.LogError(exc, $"Unable to commit transaction. Original message: {exc.Message}.");
                await Session.AbortTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);
                throw;
            }
        }

        _commands.RemoveAll(x => true);

        return _commands.Count;
    }

    //...
}
```

Repository:

```
public virtual async Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity)
{
    try
    {
        await _collection.InsertOneAsync(_context.Session, entity).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return entity;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var userName in userNames)
{
    document.Name = userName + "something";
    document.UserName = userName;
    _context.AddCommand(() => repo.InsertAsync(document));
}
```

The problem is that after on saving the changes I'm getting the following error from Mongo Atlas: `MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException : Command insert failed: Only servers in a sharded cluster can start a new transaction at the active transaction number`. I'm not quite understand why it's happening as I have a replica set, not a standalone server. After some googling I found only this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2974. I tried to run commands one by one, but the problem remained.
My connection string I got from Mongo Atlas is the following:
`mongodb+srv://<user_name>:<pwd>@cluster0.pulnl.azure.mongodb.net/<dbName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
For some reason there is no replica set name in the connection string. Is it related to the fact that I have a free tier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, according to the [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2974) I mentioned above, the Sessions are not multi-thread (or multi-Task) safe. But here:

`var commandTasks = _commands.Select(c => c()).ToList();`

I'm already starting multiple tasks and doesn't matter if I'm waiting for all of them either with `Task.WhenAll()` or `foreach(...)` they still are becoming running in parallel.

The solution would be to `await` each `Task` one by one:

```
// var commandTasks = _commands.Select(c => c()).ToList(); // - I removed this line.
foreach (var commandTask in _commands)
{
    await commandTask();
}
```